# Sequential animations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, sequential

I'm trying to create an animation using HTML5 canvas and Javascript. I have very little prior knowledge of Javascript. The first part of the animation is to make a circle 'grow' until the edge touches a cross. The cross then moves along the edge of the circle. Individually, these parts work fine but, as I'm using `setInterval()`, both animations play at the same time rather than waiting for the first to finish before starting the second.

What would be the easiest way to do this? I would be happy using HTML buttons, but `<button onclick="setInterval(aRot,30);">Next Step</button>` doesn't seem to work.

​My 'orrible 'odgepodge of code is viewable at http://jsfiddle.net/jtYkN/12/

Comment: You could use something along the lines of [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) to make your life easier.

Comment: The easiest way depends on how you are currently performing the animations. Might we see your code?

Comment: Why not perform a simple check to figure out when the first anim finishes and _then_ run the second? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Charmander I've added the code to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you really want to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) rather than setInterval. Its made specifically for animations. [According to paul irish](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)..

> **Why should I use it?**
>
> The browser can optimize concurrent animations together into a single
>   reflow and repaint cycle, leading to higher fidelity animation. For
>   example, JS-based animations synchronized with CSS transitions or SVG
>   SMIL. Plus, if you're running the animation loop in a tab that's not
>   visible, the browser won't keep it running, which means less CPU, GPU,
>   and memory usage, leading to much longer battery life.

Heres how I would implement what your talking about

```
// all credit to paul irish on this part
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();


function growCircle () {
  // code to make the circle bigger
}


function rotateCross() {
  // code to make the cross rotate
}

(function animate(){
  requestAnimFrame(animate);
  if ( /* code to tell if the circle has finished growing */ ) {
    rotateCross();
  } else {
    growCircle();
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! This works very well. After some refactoring, I'm using a switch statement on a string 'phase' in my animate() function. Just in case you're curious, http://jsfiddle.net/SSW29/